# PreAuthorize annotation not working after Spring Boot 3 migration

Tags: spring-security, java-17

We are trying to migrate our applications from Java 8 + Spring Boot 2 to Java 17 + Spring Boot 3. Pretty much everything is working apart from our API calls that are annotated with @PreAuthorize.

Here is a simplified version of our Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter( new JwtAuthenticationConverter() );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(
                properties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri()).build();

        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}

class JwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, new JwtAuthoritiesConverter().convert(jwt));
    }
    
}

class JwtAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SOME_AUTHORITY"));

        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

}
```

And a sample method in question:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SOME_AUTHORITY')")
    @GetMapping("/someObjects") APIResponse<SomeObject> testMethod(JwtAuthenticationToken principal){
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> principalAuthorities= principal.getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info("Authorities: " + principalAuthorities.toString());
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.info("Security Context" + authorities.toString());
        
        return APIResponse.singleton(new SomeObject());
    }
```

Taking out the PreAuthorize annotation allows us to reach the method and print the GrantedAuthorities, which appear to be correct:

> 2023-06-28T09:48:27,618 INFO  SomeController::testMethod(223): Authorities: [SOME_AUTHORITY]
> 2023-06-28T09:48:27,618 INFO  SomeController: Security Context[SOME_AUTHORITY]

However adding it back in causes an HTTP 401 to be returned. We also see these logs when trace is enabled:

> 2023-06-28T11:27:13,166 DEBUG o.s.s.o.s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter::doFilterInternal(143): Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@eb761cc7, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[SOME_AUTHORITY]]

...

> 2023-06-28T11:27:13,174 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter::handleAuthenticationException(184): Sending to authentication entry point since authentication failed
> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Is there anything we can check to trace this further? The same code appears to be working fine in our old code base (with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter).

Edit:
It appears PreAuthorize works for us if we set:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL);
```

instead of:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
```

Any explanation would be very much appreciated here.

Comment: I assume you have followed the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-security)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we've followed the migration guide. Also editing the post to indicate that a change in the SecurityContextHolder strategy appears to be working for us.

Comment: the documentation states that MODE_THREADLOCAL is the default strategy https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html this is also shown in the source code as the default https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/2dee6218b5efede4debadb416750fb8cd8b33f6d/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.java#L86 so i feel the asker is not giving us the full picture

Comment: We use SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL because we have @Async-annotated methods where we want to carry over the current security token--this part is broken after updating to MODE_THREADLOCAL. Which parts should I provide to give you the full picture?

Comment: Thanks dude. Your suggestion at the end saved my life. This is not mentioned in mig guide from 2.7 to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following annotation on config file:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Comment: Not possible for us, but thanks--@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity is deprecated in Spring Boot 3.x

Comment: Can you share your loadByUserNameMethod() ?