# Spring Boot api gives 403 after lots of successful 200 responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot app which uses spring security as a dependency. I am migrating Spring boot version from 2.7.16 to 3.2.1. Everything works fine in version 2.7.16. But in 3.2.1, the rest APIs give 403 after a while. Sometimes 5 mins later, sometimes 1 hour later. So, it gives 200 successful responses in the beginning, but gives 403 after some time. I couldn't fix the issue after many attempts. I am sharing security configs. Any help is appreciated

2.7.16 security config;

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/manage/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/manage/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter())
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(HeaderConstants.PRINCIPAL_HEADER);
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(new HeaderAuthenticationDetailsSource());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

And here is 3.2.1 security config;

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/manage/info")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/manage/health")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilter(authenticationFilter())
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
        ;

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(HeaderConstants.PRINCIPAL_HEADER);
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(new HeaderAuthenticationDetailsSource());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(new PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Logs:

[Debug logs](https://pastebin.pl/view/825fb0c3)

```
2024-01-05T18:59:40.276Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2024-01-05T18:59:40.279Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-01-05T18:59:40.281Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2024-01-05T18:59:40.282Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2024-01-05T18:59:40.282Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-01-05T18:59:40.283Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-05T18:59:40.284Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
2024-01-05T18:59:40.285Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Fri Jan 05 18:59:40 GMT 2024, status=403, error=Forbidden, path=/worklogEntries/health}]
2024-01-05T18:59:40.288Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-05T18:59:40.288Z DEBUG 1 --- [xxxx-time] [nio-8061-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

Comment: Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Comment: logs are added @dur

Comment: These are Jenkins logs, not your application log. I don't understand the role of Jenkins in you question.

Comment: I shared app logs as well. Jenkins log is just a bonus. But above the Jenkins log, there is already application logs.

Comment: why are you posting app logs when we asked for `DEBUG` logs, please look up how to enable debug logs

Comment: I added more detailed logs @dur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. To get rid of the issue I had to set SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL); explicitly in SecurityFilterChain method in SecurityConfig class. This value is default but it's overwritten somewhere else in my project. This was not an issue in version 2.7 but now it's an issue in version 3.

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76569289/preauthorize-annotation-not-working-after-spring-boot-3-migration)